# Separating Facebook likes with a comma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, koala

I am using the koala gem within Ruby on Rails, and I am able to display the list of people that liked a post, but I would like to have them separated by a comma

```
- likes_list(feed['id'])[0,6].each do |like|
  = like['name'].to_sentence
```

above is what I have attempted to use without any success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?  `likes_list(feed['id'])[0,6].map{|u| u['name']}.join(',')`